# Angular spyOn ngrx/store inside a Promise scope

Tags: angular, promise, ngrx

I'm writing a Test with Angular TestBed with the following setup:

```
let cacheService: CacheService;
let store: Store<PsaAppState>;
let service: ConfigService;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      ConfigService,
      { provide: TranslateService, useValue: getMock(TranslateService) },
      { provide: CacheService, useValue: getMock(CacheService) },
      { provide: Store, useValue: getMock(Store) }
    ]
  });
  const injector: TestBed = getTestBed();
  service = injector.get(ConfigService);
  cacheService = injector.get(CacheService);
  store = injector.get(Store);
});
```

The test looks like this:

```
it('Should dispatch FetchFeatureConfigAction when promise is rejected', () => {
    spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.stub();
    spyOn(cacheService, 'getRawItem').and.returnValue(Promise.reject('error'));

    service.getFeatureConfig();
    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new FetchFeatureConfigAction());
});
```

The code it tests look like this:

```
getFeatureConfig() {
    console.log('###Service called!!!');
    this.cacheService.getRawItem('APP_STATE_NAME').then(
      (appState: PsaAppState) => {
        console.log('###Resolve with ', appState);
        !isNil(appState.featureConfigState.featureConfig)
          ? this.store$.dispatch(new FetchFeatureConfigSuccessAction(appState.featureConfigState.featureConfig))
          : this.store$.dispatch(new FetchFeatureConfigAction());
      },
      err => {
        console.log('###Rejected with ', err);
        this.store$.dispatch(new FetchFeatureConfigAction());
      }
    );
  }
```

I can see the logs in the rejected callback (also in the resolved for other tests) but the expects are failing with no interaction. My assumption is that to mock `this.store$.dispatch` in a **Promis scope** is the issue.

Is this assumption correct and how can I make this test run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is that the Promise is not resolved yet when the service is called and the `console.log` is executed. This is due to the way the Javascript **Event Loop** is handling asynchronous requests.

The fix to the error case is following:

```
it('Should dispatch FetchFeatureConfigAction when promise is rejected', () => {
    spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.stub();
    const expectedPromise = Promise.reject('error');
    spyOn(cacheService, 'getRawItem').and.returnValue(expectedPromise);

    service.determineFeatureConfig();
    expectedPromise.catch(() => {
      expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new FetchFeatureConfigAction());
    });
});
```

I extracted the Promise to a variable and then inside the **catch** the expects are working fine.

For the good cases the solution can be either with **then** or **async/await** syntax. An example for the latter would look like this:

```
it('Should dispatch FetchFeatureConfigAction when promise is resolved', async () => {
    spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.stub();
    const expectedPromise = Promise.resolve('success');
    spyOn(cacheService, 'getRawItem').and.returnValue(expectedPromise);

    service.determineFeatureConfig();
    await expectedPromise;
    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new FetchFeatureConfigAction());
});
```